# Insertion Sort of a list in common LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, insertion-sort

I have a code on insertion sort of a list in LISP. I have no IDEA why this is not working.. HELP

```
(defun insertionSort (myList)
    (if (null myList)
        '()
        (insertInPlace (car myList) (insertionSort (cdr myList)))))
enter code her
(defun insertInPlace (e myList)
    (if (null myList)
        (cons e '())
        (if (<= e (car myList))
             (cons e myList)
             (cons (car myList) (insertInPlace e (cdr myList))))))

(setq n (read))
(setq n (- n 1))
(setq d (read))
(setq myList (list d))
(dotimes (i n)
     (setq d (read))
     (setq myList (cons d myList))
)
(write myList)
(insertionSort(myList))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" what error do you get? what is up with "enter code her"? why are you trying to execute `myList` as a function with no arguments before passing that to `insertionSort`

Answer (score 1):

The sorting itself seems to work, so the problem is with reading input from the user.

First, you should not use `SETQ` to introduce variables. The correct options would be either [`LET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm), [`DEFVAR` or `DEFPARAMETER`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm). You should read the chapter on [variables](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html) in the book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). However, in this program you don't necessarily need to use any of them.

The second problem is that when you call `INSERTIONSORT`, you wrapped the argument `MYLIST` in parentheses. In Lisps, things inside parentheses are generally treated as function calls. Since `MYLIST` is a variable rather than a function, that will cause an error. The correct way to call it would of course be:

```
(insertionSort myList)
```

Note, btw, that the naming convention in Lisps is to use lower case with dashes between words instead of camelCase. So it would be better to name the function `insertion-sort` and the variable `my-list`.

`READ` is not a very secure way of reading input. It's better to use `PARSE-INTEGER` together with `READ-LINE` to read numbers from the user. For a better user experience, you should also print some kind of a prompt before reading input. Here's a small helper function to do that:

```
(defun prompt-for-number (prompt)
  "Display PROMPT and read a number from the user."
  (do ((number nil (parse-integer (read-line *query-io*) :junk-allowed t)))
      (number number)
    (write-string prompt *query-io*)
    (finish-output *query-io*)))
```

Using that, we can ask the user for numbers to sort (and sort them) like this:

```
(insertionSort (loop 
                  repeat (prompt-for-number "How many numbers: ")
                  collecting (prompt-for-number "Number: ")))
```